# Transform the type from argument to template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I am refactoring some old code that used its own type handling system which provided a special macro for a type to be used as an argument:

```
x = function(TYPE(double), y);
```

After the refactoring, the above is written as

```
x = function<double>(y);
```

Is there any way (using a macro or an overloaded function) to keep the old style working as well, providing the backward compatibility? I tried something like this:

```
#define TYPE(x) (x)
#define function(x, y) function<x>(y)
```

hoping that the macro will be used only when the actual number of arguments matches its definition, but this leads to compilation errors.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the compilation errors?

Comment: For one, the compiler doesn't like `function < (double) > (y)`.

Comment: Oops, these brackets are indeed my fault. I am too used to protect myself with them in macro definitions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template< class Type >
void function( int x ) {}

#define TYPE( t ) t()
template< class Type >
void function( Type, int x ) { function< Type >( x ); }
```

---

EDIT: more generally, e.g. if you want to support `void`, you can do …

```
template< class Type >
void function( int ) {}

template< class Type >
struct TypeCarrier {};

#define TYPE( t ) TypeCarrier< t >()
template< class Type >
void function( TypeCarrier< Type >, int x ) { function< Type >( x ); }

int main()
{
    function( TYPE( double ), 1 );
    function( TYPE( void ), 2 );
}
```

Comment: That fixes the definition. G-s also wants it to work in places where it is called. `function(TYPE(int), 42)` becomes `function(int(), 42)`.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I'm sorry, I fail to parse your comment. I suggest if you don't understand the above, try it out. Or if "fixes the definition" refers to the name `function`, well the OP is a bit unclear on that, but if he want's different names he will just have to define them: names must be defined anyway before being used.

Comment: @DavidHammen: if you managed to get errors on it, then i humbly suggest that you have tried too hard. when you say "I tried the above and got boatloads of errors" it seems to indicate that you have edited one file and compiled another, or a similar silly error. if you still fail to make it work after this, please post an SO question about it with your full source code and error messages.

Comment: It does work for me. Thank you! I don't understand, though, how empty brackets in t() work. Could you explain please?

Comment: it creates the default value of the type. this code only supports simple types, as apparently the original scheme did. complication can be added to support general user-defined types, including ones that can't be default-constructed, if necessary, but hopefully you won't need that.

Comment: In fact, the original scheme deals with complex types as well.

Comment: The solution fails when the type is "void*". Any ideas how to solve it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is your definition of `TYPE`. Get rid of the parenthesis.

```
#define TYPE(x) x
#define function(x, y) function<x> (y)
```

THere's also a potential problem in that the template function has the same name as that function you are trying to replace. You might want to think of making that a different name. Otherwise the new usage is off limits.

```
#define TYPE(x) x
#define function(x, y) some_name_other_than_function<x> (y)
```

Comment: you really don't want to introduce lots of macros called `function`etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "the new usage is off limits"?

Comment: Your new usage would be something along the lines of `x=function<SomeType>(y);` Now suppose you do do this `#define function(x,y) function<x>(y)` The preprocessor is going to see the `function` in `x=function<SomeType>(y);` and try to expand it. You'll get a failure at the preprocessor stage. What you want is a version of Alf's answer that works, one that returns a value instead of being void.